# ISR or SSR returns null on remote

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I have a question for you. I tried a page with ISR, which does not work on the remote.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: "blocking"
    };
  };

  export const getStaticProps = async (context: { params: { slug?: string } }) => {
    const eventSlug = context.params?.slug as string;

    const eventProps = await getEventProps(eventSlug)
    const globalData = await fetchGlobalData()

    return {
      props: {
        ...eventProps,
        ...globalData,
      }
    }
  }
```

If I try it locally it works great. But when I try it on the published site, the data it retrieves from `_next/data/.../example.json` brings null and then I end up fetching the API with CSR.

The problem is that it makes the request to the API because the statically generated data is null.

I replaced ISR with SSR, and I have the same problem. The data arrives in null and ends up making a request to the API that it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your next.js version

Comment: Hey @Yilmaz "next": "^13.5.4"

Comment: U can use them only in pages directory

Comment: I'm not very sure, but something I notice is that in the same request, global data is retrieved from the navbar and footer, and it brings data; instead, the data that interests me for the specific page doesn't.

Comment: And yeah, I am working on a dynamic page in the file pages/event/[slug].tsx